# proto grror when generating gateway protoc-gen-grpc-gateway: program not found or is not executable

Tags: grpc, grpc-go, grpc-gateway

I have found similar posts but they are rather old and they sadly did not solve my issue.

I am trying to add a Gateway for my GoLang GRPC services

```make
PROJ_PATH=${CURDIR}

.PHONY: proto
proto: ## Generate protobuf code
# Compile proto files inside the project.
    protoc api.proto --proto_path=${PROJ_PATH}/proto --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=. \
            --grpc-gateway_out . \
            --grpc-gateway_opt generate_unbound_methods=true \
            --openapiv2_out . \
            --openapiv2_opt logtostderr=true \
            --openapiv2_opt generate_unbound_methods=true
```

I add the two dependencies

```bash
go get github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway
go get github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-openapiv2
```

But I still get his error

```bash
protoc-gen-grpc-gateway: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--grpc-gateway_out: protoc-gen-grpc-gateway: Plugin failed with status code 1.
make: *** [proto] Error 1
```

I had to remove the import and gateway options in the GRPC file because this error so it looks like I have the wrong plugin but reading [here](https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/tutorials/adding_annotations/#using-protoc) tells me otherwise.

```bash
google/api/annotations.proto: File not found.
api.proto:5:1: Import "google/api/annotations.proto" was not found or had errors.
make: *** [proto] Error 1
```

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "pkg/api";

import "google/api/annotations.proto";  <---- had to remove

service ApiService {
    rpc Test(TestRequest) returns (TestResponse){

        option (google.api.http) = {  <---- had to remove
            get: "/v1/test"
            body: "*"
        };
    }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

---- solved with ------

```
go install \
    github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway@latest \
    github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-openapiv2@latest
```

then add the path to the proto command

```
--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-gateway=${GOPATH}/bin/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway \
```

full command...

```
protoc api.proto --proto_path=${PROJ_PATH}/proto --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=. \
       --grpc-gateway_out . \
       --grpc-gateway_opt generate_unbound_methods=true \
       --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-gateway=${GOPATH}/bin/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway \
       --openapiv2_out . \
       --openapiv2_opt logtostderr=true \
       --openapiv2_opt generate_unbound_methods=true
```

Comment: A quick review of your question suggests that, while you're `go get`'tting the plugins, you may not be including them in the path so that `protoc` can find them. Can you `which protoc-gen-grpc-gateway`? If not, determine the destination of `go get` and add this to the path variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install the binary like so

```
go install \
    github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway@latest \
    github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/protoc-gen-openapiv2@latest
```

Then update the proto command with the path.

```
--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-gateway=${GOPATH}/bin/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway \
```

Full proto command

```
PROJ_PATH=${CURDIR}

.PHONY: proto
proto: ## Generate protobuf code
# Compile proto files inside the project.
    protoc api.proto --proto_path=${PROJ_PATH}/proto --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=. \
           --grpc-gateway_out . \
           --grpc-gateway_opt generate_unbound_methods=true \
           --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-gateway=${GOPATH}/bin/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway \
           --openapiv2_out . \
           --openapiv2_opt logtostderr=true \
           --openapiv2_opt generate_unbound_methods=true
```